# CrossWalk LITE integration with Cordova

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I've created a Cordova project and downloaded the Crosswalk-Lite zip file. My problem is that I don't know what to do next. The docu only says: "Same as crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html " but this page explains how to to install regular Crosswalk, not Lite.

The [documentation](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Crosswalk-Project-Lite) to integrate Crosswalk Lite with Cordova is a bit ambiguous. Can someone give a more specific explanation about the steps to follow to make it work?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: Sure. I've created a Cordova project and downloaded the Crosswalk-Lite zip file. My problem is that I don't know what to do next. The docu only says: "Same as https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html " but this page explains how to to install regular Crosswalk, not Lite.

Comment: As you quoted, the [page](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Crosswalk-Project-Lite) explicitly says "If you want crosswalk-lite (for a new project), just download the crosswalk-lite .zip (instead of the full Crosswalk), and follow exactly the same install/build instructions."  Which I cited below.  Q: Have you tried this?  Q: What (if anything) didn't work for you?

Comment: Well, as Paul suggested below I'm using Cordova 4.0 or higher, so I was following the Cordova 4.0+ instructions ( https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_4.html ). These instructions don't have any reference to a .zip file, that's why I was so confused and decided to make this post. I've just read the Cordova 3.x instructions and I finally could make it work (although I'm still using Cordova 5). I guess there was a communicaton problem between you and me, anyway my problem is solved so thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 3):

Per the documentation:

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_4.html

1. Your best bet is to make sure you have Cordova 4.0 or higher (the current version is 5.1.1).
2. Download and install the Android SDK (which, of course, you'll always need).
3. Download and install Node.js and the Cordova CLI (Cordova CLI relies on Node/NPM).
4. Download and install Crosswalk and/or Crosswalk-Lite
5. Use Cordova CLI to create a project platform (as you would with any Cordova project)

   `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld; cd hello; cordova platform add android`
6. Build with Crosswalk WebView engine for Android (this is the "integration magic")

   `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`
7. Implement your app (as you would any Crosswalk or Cordova project)
8. Use the Cordova CLI to build the implemented project (as you would any Cordova app):

   `cordova build android`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul. What I needed was the explanation of the fourth step, this is, what to do with the Crosswalk-Lite files (https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk-lite/android/canary/). Two more things: The current Crosswalk-Lite version is 10, are you sure it will be compatible with Cordova 4? The sixth step won't install the official version instead of Lite?

Answer (score 3):

And how about using [**Ionic Framework**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/)?
It simplifies all things.

So, using Ionic you could choose among all available browser listed by the Ionic CLI command `ionic browser list`.
Output example:

```
Android - Browsers Listing:

Available - Crosswalk - ionic browser add crosswalk
         Version 8.37.189.14 Published
         Version 9.38.208.10 Published
         Version 10.39.235.15 Published
         Version 11.40.277.7 Published
         Version 12.41.296.5 Published
(beta)   Version 13.42.319.6 Published
(canary) Version 14.42.334.0 Published

Available - Crosswalk-lite - ionic browser add crosswalk-lite
(canary) Version 10.39.234.1 Published
(canary) Version 10.39.236.1 Published
```

Then, for example, install an [alternate browser](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/browsers.html) with the command:

```
ionic browser add crosswalk-lite@10.39.236.1
```